# One to many relationship crud

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am currently working with Asp.NEt Core 6. I would like to create CRUD with one to many relationship between two Models (Staffs and Tax). The idea is to have one staff have several tax entries.

**Staff Model**

```cs
namespace Join.Models
{
    public class Staff
    {
        [Key]
        public int staffid { get; set; }
        public string staffname { get; set; }
        public int salary { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

**Tax Model**

```cs
namespace Join.Models
{
    public class Paye
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Staff")]
        public int staffid { get; set; }
        public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I do not know how to code the controllers and views

Comment: please have a look at this::-> https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1031778/Configure-One-To-Many-Relationship-in-MVC-and

Comment: Please adhere to naming conventions. By convention public propertis are pascal-cased. If you want to use camel-case, then fine by me, but why not be consistent? Why is it CreatedDate and amount instead of CreatedDate and Amount or createdDate and amount?

Comment: After you change the model like what @Cr1stal's answer do, then scaffold the crud operations and if any changes you can modify the generated code. Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0#create-controller-and-views

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```
    namespace Join.Models
   {
    public class Staff
    {
        [Key]
        public int staffid { get; set; }
        public string staffname { get; set; }
        public int salary { get; set; }
        
        public virtual List<Paye> taxEntries {get; set; }
        
    }
}

namespace Join.Models
{
    public class Paye
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public int staffid { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("staffid")]
        public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And i would recommend you make a migration after these changes